# Where does Android keep dll assemblies of Xamarin applications

Tags: android, dll, xamarin

I am trying to find dll libraries on my rooted Android device after installing the application developed via Xamarin. However, I can'f find them anywhere. Does anyone know where I should looking for them?

Comment: they are packaged inside of the apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unzip the `.apk` you will find a directory structure like the following example, and the CIL-based assemblies are location within the `assemblies` directory:

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   ├── SUSHIHAN.RSA
│   └── SUSHIHAN.SF
├── NOTICE
├── assemblies
│   ├── FilePicker.dll
│   ├── Java.Interop.dll
│   ├── Mono.Android.dll
│   ├── System.Core.dll
│   ├── System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
│   ├── System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
│   ├── System.Xml.dll
│   ├── System.dll
│   └── mscorlib.dll
├── classes.dex
├── environment
├── lib
│   └── armeabi-v7a
│       ├── libaot-FilePicker.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-Java.Interop.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-Mono.Android.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-System.Core.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-System.Xml.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-System.dll.so
│       ├── libaot-mscorlib.dll.so
│       ├── libmonodroid.so
│       └── libmonosgen-2.0.so
├── res
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── main.xml
│   ├── mipmap-hdpi-v4
│   │   └── icon.png
│   ├── mipmap-mdpi-v4
│   │   └── icon.png
│   ├── mipmap-xhdpi-v4
│   │   └── icon.png
│   ├── mipmap-xxhdpi-v4
│   │   └── icon.png
│   └── mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4
│       └── icon.png
├── resources.arsc
├── typemap.jm
└── typemap.mj
```